# PRG implies OWF Proof

Tags: pseudo-random-generator, one-way-function

[image]
I got the idea of this proof, that since PRG expands from n to 2n, it cannot project to all {0,1}^{2n}, only to a neglible part which we can abuse to make a good distinguisher just by telling if A succeeds finding a preimage in X. A random string from U2n has very likely no preimage in X. Thus we can distinguish U2n from G(Un). But I think I do not understand the construction f well.
What's the purpose of our y? Can we not just proof this using f(x) := G(x)?
Also why is f variable? If we define f like that, shouldn't it be a projection from 2n to 2n? I miss something.

Comment: The definition of a OWF being used there probably requires the function to be length preserving. Since G is expanding you need to pad the input.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. I skipped back to page 40: "In the sequel, we shall deal only with one-way functions that are length-regular [...] mostly with length-preserving functions". I use Goldreichs book to read proofs that our lecture is not talking about, so I should be more careful. Thanks.

Comment: Your question is a pain to read. Please use mathjax

Comment: @kodlu I learn some Latex currently, I will definitely try to use it in my next question.